# I am a newbie to python and I am having problems installing pygame?

Tags: pygame

I just downloaded pygame 32-bit on a 32-bit macintosh pro. I opened IDLE and typed in import pygame in IDLE shell then click enter. Usually I've heard that it should just return but it gives me the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: Are you sure it is not a 64-bit machine? This error generally occurs when trying to use 32-bit pygame with 64-bit Python. If it's the default install of Python on a 64-bit Mac then this is likely the problem. Unless it is quite an old machine it would likely be 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say if this is a problem of 32/64 bits installation, but you can easily check which version you are running :

```
import struct; print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))
```

Comment: I am having the same problem... however, I don't know how to fix this.  I have python.org's 2.7.8 and python 3.4.1 installed.. but it finds 2.7.8 which shows the error..

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you typed py or python3 so it popped up >>> in your terminal so I would download it and do this:
Make sure there is no >>> if there is the only solution I found was the restart the terminal
First download it like this I will be using 3.9 for the version for example:

```
py -3.9 -m pip install pygame
```

then use this to check if it downloaded

```
py -3.9 -m pygame --version
```

Then open up IDLE - Python [VERSION] and then new file and type `import pygame` and this should work!